# SAPUI5 - Smartfields: Value help based on local mockdata sample not working with CDS

Tags: typescript, annotations, sapui5, cds

I want to have a simple value help popup.
My goal is to not reinvent any wheels and also to use CDS + proper annotations in combination with a smartfield to get a value help as easy and quick as possible, inside a pure SAPUI5 freestyle app.

The sample, I want to reproduce:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.96.20/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartField/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfield.WithValueListAndConstantParameter

Field 1 is enough.

The CDS stack ( join of MEAN + MAKTX ) looks like this:

[image]

The preview generator in the service binding seems to show that stuff properly ( OdataV2_UI ):

[image]

The root entity node is exposed as "current_vh", which is read in like this:

```
 public onInit(): void {

    var oComponent = this.getOwnerComponent();
    oModelGlob = oComponent.getModel() as ODataModel;            
    oModelGlob.setDefaultBindingMode("TwoWay");        

    let smartF = this.byId("searchForm"); 
    

     const res = oModelGlob.read("/current_vh/", {
        success:function(oData:any, response:any) 
        {
            console.log("Read successfull");     

            debugger;            

            smartF.bindElement( { path: "/current_vh('907')" } );                                               


            //return oData;                                                        
        },                
        error:function(oError:any) 
        {                
            console.log("Read failed");                
        }
    });
```

But what I see, is not responsive, in fact it is a label, read only.
Like this:

[image]

Anyone a clue ? Shall I add my generated metadata as well ?
Because, If I inspect my  local metadata, which was fetched in BAS after publishing the service in eclipse, all the proper nodes seem to fit, yet, I have no value help behaviour.
But I want to have it, like in the posted link.